# Adding PHP into Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert PHP into a Wordpress function but I cannot seem to get the formatting correct!

The function I am working on is:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_admin_link', 10, 2);

function add_admin_link($items, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-menu' ){
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. esc_url( admin_url() ) .'">' . __( 'Admin' ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I am trying to make the function output the following php:

```
<a href="<?php the_field('field-name-1'); ?>">
    <?php the_field('field-name-1'); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I have been unable to find the right formatting to display my desired PHP code within the Wordpress function detailed in the first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using advance custom field, then you'd have to use `get_field` to get a return value instead of `the_field` that directly print/echo the value.

you can do something like this assuming you know that meta value will change depending on what page you are viewing

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_admin_link', 10, 2);

function add_admin_link($items, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-menu' ){
        $items .= '<a href="'. get_field('field-name-1').'">'. get_field('field-name-1').'</a>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for thank you. I almost got it when I tried before, just needed to change to the get_field in my markup. Thank you again :)